# Counter example for M. Riesz conjugate function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

M. Riesz claim than for $1 < p < \infty$, that $A_p$ is constant:
$$|| \psi h||_p \leq A_p||h||_p$$
$$ \psi h(z) = \int_T \frac{e^{it}+z}{e^{it}-z} h(e^{it})d\rho
$$
The counter example for p = $\infty$ is given by conformal mapping of U to a vertical strip, But I cannot figure out p = 1 one.

Comment: Essentially the logarithm gives this (eg take $h(z)=\arg (1-z)=\Im \log (1-z)$ using the principal branch in the unit disc so this is bounded by $\pi/2$ as $\Re (1-z)  > 0$ but its conjugate is $\log|(1-z)|$ which is unbounded)

Comment: @David - I realized that actually the OP wants a counterxample for $p=1$ not $p=\infty$ so my example doesn't answer the question as it is for $p=\infty$; on the other hand yours works as for $p=1$ the Poisson Kernel is in $H^1$ (it's positive after all, so its integral on any circle is the same as the integral of the absolute value and is constant by harmonicity), but its conjugate is not in $H^1$ by a simple compuation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional argument for $p=1$ is to use duality, showing that if the inequality held for $p=1$ then it would hold for $p=\infty$. One can give an explicit example: Let  $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1-\overline z}{|1-z|^2}=u+iv\quad(|z|<1).$$So $$u(re^{it})=\frac{1-r\cos(t)}{1-2r\cos(t)+r^2}, v(re^{it})=\frac{-r\sin(t)}{1-2r\cos(t)+r^2}\quad(0\le r<1).$$

Now since $u\ge0$ it's clear that $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|u(re^{it})|\,dt=u(0).$$(Thanks to Conrad for pointing this out.) Otoh $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|v(re^{it})|\,dt$$must be unbounded, because otherwise $f\in H^1(\Bbb D)$, which would imply that the boundary values of $f$ on the circle were integrable.

Comment: David, Thanks for you example, But I wonder how to easily to construct the count example. I feel that I lack some thing to think out of it.